# What is the difference between loop device and block device?

Tags: linux, devices, loop-device

I want to create a loop device myself, I want it to have a special name, say `/dev/loop-test-0`. I want it to be up after I reboot the machine. I though that I can use `mknod` for this, but this doesn't seem to work. I look on the other loop device I have in the system and they all look like

```
brw-rw----. 1 root disk   7,   0 Jul 27 09:35 /dev/loop0
```

I added number with `mknod /dev/loop8 b 7 8` so it looks like

```
brw-rw----. 1 root disk   7,   8 Jul 27 11:32 /dev/loop8
```

When I use `losetup /dev/loop8 testfs` I get `losetup: /dev/loop8: failed to set up loop device: No such device or address` while when I use `losetup /dev/loop0 testfs` I get no error.

What is the problem? I don't want to use

```
echo loop > /etc/modules-load.d/loop.conf
echo options loop max_loop=8 > /etc/modprobe.d/eightloop.conf
```

I want to create loop devices myself, is it possible?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you *don't* want to increase the number of available loop devices yet you still want to use loop device numbers beyond the current maximum. Please choose whether to have your cake or to eat it.

Comment: Also, the title of your question "What is the difference between loop device and block device?" has nothing to do with the body of your question. Please clarify.

Comment: @Celada I think e271p314 just wants to create a loop device that doesn't follow the `loop${n}` naming scheme.

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to control the name of the loop device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A loop device is a particular type of block device, managed by the loop device driver. A [loop device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device) is a block device whose content is stored in a file, similar to the way a SCSI disk device is a block device whose content is stored on a SCSI disk, a USB storage device is a block device whose content is stored on a USB storage peripheral, etc.

Linux has a kernel parameter which determines the number of loop devices that can be used on the system. Creating entries in `/dev` will not change that number: you have as many devices as the driver allows, no more. If you create additional entries, there's no driver to handle them, hence the error “No such device or address” (ENODEV) when you try to access that device.

On a modern Linux system (from the last decade or thereabouts), [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) automatically creates entries in `/dev`, so creating entries manually is not needed — if the entry isn't there, it means you don't have the corresponding driver.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Is there a way I can give one of the loop devices a unique name that I choose (and by this guarantee nobody else will uses it)

Comment: @e271p314 You can give a loop device another name, but that won't prevent others from using it. What determines the identity of a device is the major and minor numbers (the “7, 0” in the output of `ls -l /dev/loop0`), not the path to the file in `/dev`. Use `losetup -f --show`.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your answers, it is clear you know what you are talk about :-)